# how to implement something like this tableview? or viewcontroller or uialert? SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uipopovercontroller, viewcontroller

[Picture Images to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CMjI.jpg)

Hi I'm having a hard time implementing something like this, is this a uiviewcontroller with a popup segue or a tableview controller? or just a simple alert? can anyone help me or can you provide a link with tutorials like this regards

Comment: This [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)

There is an example what you like.